# When considering titles of scientific papers, why are definite and indefinite articles omitted sometimes?

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles, titles

Is it a rule or is it a sign of bad English among foreign researchers and scientists?

Example: Observation of Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen Entanglement on Supraquantum Structures by Induction Through Nonlinear Transuranic Crystal of Extremely Long Wavelength Pulse from Mode-Locked Source Array

I think there are at least three indefinite articles missing, and possibly some definite articles.
1) Through a nonlinear transuranic crystal
2) an extremely long wavelength pulse
3) a mode locked source array

I'm a non-native speaker, so any thoughts on this topic are very welcome!

Comment: Titles of articles, papers and books do not have to be complete, grammatically correct sentences. So words are left out simply to reduce the length of the title (which, as the example shows, can be long enough anyway).

Comment: I thought definite and indefinite articles are supposed to bear some information, and some terms without them may sound less intelligent. But can I omit all of the articles in the title of my thesis if it's not that long? Let's say 7 words.

Comment: Not if it's << Omitting a and the in titles >>.  There's no overarching body pronouncing on absolute right and wrong in these grey areas. Look in the style guide accompanying your course, look at similar examples written previously, ask a tutor.

Comment: English isn't the primary language in my uni, but I'm supposed to submit an article in English and after asking other people and surfing the web, I'm still a bit confused because I can't see a definitive pattern. Some people say I shouldn't be focusing on that too much but I just want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Use of articles is avoided in headings, abstracts (at least reduced), foot-notes, diagrams, etc., but are used in the main text/ discussions. Use of too many articles doesn't seem to be the fashion of the day.